# Regular expression and Boost

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a problem with the following regex in boost:

```
const boost::regex eComment("^\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|^\/\/");
```

When I run program with this regex, it's aborted with message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::regex_error> >'

what():  Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  
The error occured while parsing the regular expression: '^/*[sS]*?*>>>HERE>>>/|^//'.
```

This regexp should find lines with comment in `*.cpp` file, but should skip if there is code in the line.

Comment: I don't know anything about boost, but I think you may have an issue.  [\s\S] translates to "a whitespace char OR not a whitespace char".  I think it should be one or the other.  And normally forward slashes don't need to be escaped in a regex (unless it is Perl and the / is your delimiter).

Comment: I think what you want is this.  ^\s*(/\*.*?\*/|//)  ... start of line plus zero of more spaces followed by the comment.  And the comment is either "/* any number of chars */" or "// anything".  If you need to escape backslashes because they are special in C, then it would be ^\\s*(/\\*.*?\\*/|//)

Comment: `[\s\S]*?` = `0 or 1 of 1 or more characters`?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you forgot to escape the backslash characters. Each backslash should be doubled like \\s\\S instead of \s\S

Hope it helps